# Why does a 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object have no attribute 'cell'?

Tags: python, cell, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.Workbook("multiplication.xlsx")
wb.create_sheet()
sheet=wb.get_active_sheet()

sheet.cell(column=6, row=4).value= 5

wb.save("multiplication.xlsx")
```

When i try and write in the cell, I receive this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bjg/Desktop/excel2.py", line 8, in <module>
    sheet.cell(column=6, row=4).value= 5
AttributeError: 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'cell'
```

I was wondering if anybody knew why this was the case?

Answer (score 5):

From the [write-only mode docs](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#write-only-mode):

> In a write-only workbook, rows can only be added with `append()`. It is not possible to write (or read) cells at arbitrary locations with `cell()` or `iter_rows()`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing:

```
wb=openpyxl.Workbook("multiplication.xlsx")
```

just do:

```
wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
```

then at last save with:

```
wb.save("multiplication.xlsx")
```