# Python Openpyxl - Add column in write_only spreadsheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using Python and openpyxl library, but, I'm not able to use the `insert_cols()` function in openpyxl when my spreadsheet is in `write_only=True` mode. So, basically, **I just want to add a new column to my spreadsheet when it's in `write_only=True` mode.**

I'm able to use `insert_cols()` when loading the workbook by `load_workbook()`, but, not when I'm using the `write_only` mode. I have to use the `write_only` mode because my spreadsheets are quite large.

Any ideas on how to add a new column are appreciated.

Thank you.

**This is my code:**

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename=r'path\myExcel.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['PC Details']

wb_output = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws_output = wb_output.create_sheet(title='PC Details')


for row in ws.rows:
    rowInCorrectFormat = [cell.value for cell in row]
    ws_output.append(rowInCorrectFormat)
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)

### THIS IS THE PART OF THE CODE WHICH DOES NOT WORK
ws_output.insert_cols(12)
ws_output['L5'] = 'OK or NOT GOOD?'
###

wb_output.save(r'path\test_Output_optimized.xlsx')
```

**This is the exact error that I'm getting:**

```
ws_output.insert_cols(12)
AttributeError: 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'insert_cols'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313365/why-does-a-writeonlyworksheet-object-have-no-attribute-cell

Comment: @DhirendraKumar I do not agree that this is a duplicate. In my question I'm asking how to do add a new column, and, in the question that you provided there's only a question in regards to `cell` attribute.

Comment: It is suggesting that the Workbook object in write only mode has some limitations and does not support inserting values at arbitrary locations. It only support data insertion by Append method. Hence, you should not use WriteOnly mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here lies in the flag `write_only = True`. Workbooks created by this flag set to true are different from regular Workbooks as you can look below.

[image]

Functions like insert_cols & insert_rows also do not work for such workbooks.

Possible solutions might be to not use this flag or use the ways suggested in the official documentation for adding data to the sheet.

For working with workbooks you might also find this article interesting. https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/working-with-excel-sheets-in-python-using-openpyxl-4f9fd32de87f

You can read more in the official documentation. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html